# Why does this implementation of Josef Stein's Binary GCD Algorithm only work for certain cases?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, runtime-error, scheme, lisp

Using scheme, I have built an iterative implementation of the Binary GCD Algorithm (aka Stein's Algorithm) to compute the Greatest Common Denominator of numbers `u` and `v`.  The steps to this algorithm are as follows:

1. gcd(0, v) = v, because everything divides zero, and v is the largest number that divides v. Similarly, gcd(u, 0) = u. gcd(0, 0) is not typically defined, but it is convenient to set gcd(0, 0) = 0.
2. If u and v are both even, then gcd(u, v) = 2·gcd(u/2, v/2), because 2 is a common divisor.
3. If u is even and v is odd, then gcd(u, v) = gcd(u/2, v), because 2 is not a common divisor. Similarly, if u is odd and v is even, then gcd(u, v) = gcd(u, v/2).
4. If u and v are both odd, and u ≥ v, then gcd(u, v) = gcd((u − v)/2, v). If both are odd and u < v, then gcd(u, v) = gcd((v − u)/2, u). These are combinations of one step of the simple Euclidean algorithm, which uses subtraction at each step, and an application of step 3 above. The division by 2 results in an integer because the difference of two odd numbers is even.
5. Repeat steps 2–4 until u = v, or (one more step) until u = 0. In either case, the GCD is 2kv, where k is the number of common factors of 2 found in step 2.

The algorithm I made is this:

```
(define (stein u v)
  (cond
    ((or (= u 0)(= u v))
      v)
    ((and (even? u) (even? v))
      (* 2 (stein (/ u 2)(/ v 2))))
    ((and (even? u) (odd? v))
      (stein (/ u 2) v))
    ((and (odd? u) (even? v))
      (stein u (/ v 2)))
    ((and (and (odd? u) (odd? v))(>= u v))
      (stein (/ 2 (- u v)) v))
    ((and (and (odd? u)(odd? v))(< u v))
      (stein (/ 2 (- v u)) u))))
```

My problem is that whenever I run into a situation where one number is odd and the other is even (either the inputs are that way or the procedure eventually calls itself that way), the output is either blank or it returns the error: `Error: *: number required, but got #<undef> [stein, stein, stein, *]`

Can somebody explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You should put a "catch all" case into your *cond* which blows up. Your cases are intended to be exhaustive, but you aren't catching the case when they aren't.  The #<undef> is coming from the fall-through in a recursive case; your lower-level *stein* falls through the *cond* and returns #<undef>. The higher-level *stein* tries to multiply that #<undef> by 2.

Comment: @Kaz how should I do that?

Comment: E.g `(cond (whatever blah) ... (#t (this shouldn't be reached)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an error in the two rows:

```
(stein (/ 2 (- u v)) v))
```

and

```
(stein (/ 2 (- v u)) u))))
```

You should divide the difference by 2, and not viceversa. That is:

```
(stein (/ (- u v) 2) v))
```

and

```
(stein (/ (- v u) 2) u))))
```

Finally, note that it is needed a test to check if the second parameter is equal to 0, otherwise in certain cases the function loops forever.

Something like this:

```
(define (stein u v)
  (cond
    ((or (= u 0)(= u v))
      v)
    ((= v 0) u)
    ((and (even? u) (even? v))
      (* 2 (stein (/ u 2)(/ v 2))))
    ((and (even? u) (odd? v))
      (stein (/ u 2) v))
    ((and (odd? u) (even? v))
      (stein u (/ v 2)))
    ((and (and (odd? u) (odd? v))(>= u v))
      (stein (/ (- u v) 2) v))
    ((and (and (odd? u)(odd? v))(< u v))
      (stein (/ (- v u) 2) u))))
```

Comment: That was something I didn't catch, but It didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Jodast, I tried it in DrRacket and it calculates correctly the GCD for all the tests that I’ve made. Which implementation of scheme are you using? What is the error or the problem that is not fixed?

Comment: Never mind, I deleted one of the parentheses when I pasted it in.  It worked!

Comment: I've just checked the algorithm for (4 0) and actually it loops forever. It is necessary to add an explicit text for `v = 0` to terminate it.

Comment: @Jodast, I've updated the answer to correct that issue.

Comment: Okay, thank you!  I didn't realize I had only done it for `u = 0`.